# Assigning variables to xml data

Tags: python, xml, zoho

I am trying to do Zoho CRM integration with my chatbot written in python. But I have to enter the values to the xml fields manually, and am not able to set them to variables. Here is the code xml data code, please check it out.

I want to automate insertion of records, hence the assigning of variables to xml data which was taken as input from the user. 
Code:

```
authtoken = '################'
params = {'authtoken': authtoken, 'scope': 'crmapi', 'newFormat': '1', 'xmlData': '<Contacts>'
    '<row no="1">'
    '<FL val="First Name">name</FL>'
    '<FL val="Last Name">ww</FL>'
    '<FL val="Email">test@test.com</FL>'
    '<FL val="Department">CG</FL>'
    '<FL val="Phone">999999999</FL>'
    '<FL val="Fax">99999999</FL>'
    '<FL val="Mobile">999825488</FL>'
    '<FL val="Assistant">John</FL>'
    '</row>'
    '</Contacts>'
final_URL = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/insertRecords"
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode("utf-8")
request = urllib.request.Request(final_URL, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
xml_response = response.read()
print(xml_response)
```

Comment: I formatted your code, please correct if I made any errors in interpreting what you intended.  Remember code blocks must be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Yeah thank you, that happened while pasting the code here. My code works, the record is getting inserted to the Contacts page of my zoho account, but I am not able to assign variables instead of manually typing in details of the user.